# Is it correct to use two 'of's very close to each other in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, redundancy

Is it correct to use two 'of's very close to each other, in the following sentence?

> A photo with the advanced stage **of** execution **of** the electronic device.

How to avoid this in my case?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using *of* multiple times in a sentence.

Comment: No problem. It's perfectly good idiomatic English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid multiple "of-phrases" in one sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16565/how-to-avoid-multiple-of-phrases-in-one-sentence)

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with your example. But if you don't like it, just rephrase to an "appositive noun" usage: *A photo with the advanced **execution stage** of the electronic device.*

Comment: It's fine, except that I have no idea what it might mean. What's a _stage of execution of the electronic device_? And what's an advanced one of those?

Answer (score 0):

"A photo with the advanced stage of execution of the electronic device."
is fine. If you find you get too many 'of's stacking up, you can occasionally re-cast. You've already avoided one potential extra.

For instance, stretching it further…
"A photo of the advanced stage of execution of the display of the device" would be just too clumsy, so
"A photo showing the advanced execution stage of the device's display" would get you nicely out of trouble.

BTW, I much prefer 'showing', or even 'of' [so long as you're not trying to avoid a stack], to 'with'. 'A photo with…' is awkward.

Comment: Thanks. I chose: A photo showing the advanced execution stage of the ....